# exclude certain mailaccounts from sound notifications

Tags: ios, mail.app, iphone, audio

In iOS6, on iPhone 5, how can I disable sound and vibration for a specific mail account only? I have one mail accounts that is a bit to highly frequented, which results in a lot of ringing and vibration. However all the other mail accounts behave just fine.

Unfortunately I only see one global setting for the whole mail app.

Comment: Maybe you can consider setting mail retrieval to Manual for this account, which will only check for new mails when opening the Mail app?

Comment: That'd be one solution, yes. Not optimal though.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to accomplish this from the Notifications section of the Settings app, which allows you to set the kind of alerts each app uses:

[image: Notifications in Settings] [image: Mail in Notifications]

In that panel, each of your mail accounts will be listed separately, and can be configured individually. I have one account, for example, set to not even badge the Mail.app icon, let alone play sound:

[image: List of accounts] [image: Settings for mail account that does not notify]